# What is wrong with my Binary Tree Insertion Code?

Tags: java, binary-tree

could someone please take a look at this portion of my insert function of my "BinaryTreeNode", I am using a JetBrains IDE (I am a learner) and it keeps telling me that "root = newNode" can never be reached?

```
     public void addNode(BinaryTreeNode root, BinaryTreeNode newNode) {
        if (root == null && newNode == null)
            return;
        else if (newNode == null)
            return;

        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare the value of the root to go to left or right then add, I assume you have in the `BinaryTreeNode` class the following:

```
class BinaryTreeNode {
    int data;
    BinaryTreeNode left, right;
}
```

```
public BinaryTreeNode addNode(BinaryTreeNode root, BinaryTreeNode newNode) {
        if (root == null || newNode == null) {
            return null;
        }
        
        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
            return root;
        }

        if (root.data < newNode.data) {
            root.right = addNode(root.right, newNode);
        } else if (root.data > newNode.data) {
            root.left = addStrings(root.left, newNode);
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I still do not know why expression in my code above is unreachable. I'd really like to understand that.